# ValueError in Dataflow: Invalid GCS location: None

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm trying to load data from GCS bucket and publish content to pubsub and bigquery. These are my pipeline options:

```
options = PipelineOptions(
      project = project,
      temp_location = "gs://dataflow-example-bucket6721/temp21/",
      region = 'us-east1',
      job_name = "dataflow2-pubsub-09072021",
      machine_type = 'e2-standard-2',
   )
```

And this is my pipeline

```
data = p | 'CreateData' >> beam.Create(sum([fileName()], []))

jsonFile =  data | "filterJson" >> beam.Filter(filterJsonfile)

JsonData = jsonFile | "JsonData" >> beam.Map(readFromJson)

split_data = JsonData | 'Split Data' >> ParDo(CheckForValidData()).with_outputs("ValidData", "InvalidData")

ValidData = split_data.ValidData
InvalidData = split_data.InvalidData
data_ = split_data[None]


publish_data = ValidData | "Publish msg" >> ParDo(publishMsg())

ToBQ = ValidData | "To BQ" >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
            table_spec,
            #schema=table_schema,
            create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
            write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND)
```

The data is flowing fine in InteractiveRunner but in DataflowRunner it is showing an error like

> ValueError: Invalid GCS location: None.
> Writing to BigQuery with FILE_LOADS method requires a GCS location to be provided to write files to be loaded into BigQuery. Please provide a GCS bucket through custom_gcs_temp_location in the constructor of WriteToBigQuery or the fallback option --temp_location, or pass method="STREAMING_INSERTS" to WriteToBigQuery. [while running '[15]: To BQ/BigQueryBatchFileLoads/GenerateFilePrefix']

It is showing error of GCS location and suggest to add temp_location. but I have already added temp_location.

Comment: error suggests `custom_gcs_temp_location`, not `temp_location`

Comment: Even with `custom_gcs_temp_location` it is showing the same error @furas

Comment: is this FULL error message? Maybe using something like `print(...)` between all lines you could localize which line makes problem.

Comment: Did you try using beam.io.Write, beam.io.BigQuerySink and see that it works instead of WriteToBigQuery? OR based on the error what I see can you pls try adding  temp_location specifically and check if it works? This is what the error suggest .I have used beam.io.Write, beam.io.BigQuerySink for my pipeline to read data from gcs to big query and never faced this issue. Yours is batch processing anyway?

Comment: Thanks for your help furas  and Radhika Sharma. I just factory reset runtime (In colab) and tried, all the things working fine now! (previously I was doing restart runtime). I don't know how but it is working now!!!

Comment: When running with Google Dataflow, you'll always need to specify a GCS temp location to store the dataflow states so here the issue isnt the bucket you're planning to write to :)

Answer (score 4):

When running your Dataflow pipeline pass the argument `--temp_location gs://bucket/subfolder/` (exactly in this format, create a subfolder inside the bucket) and should work.