# Flatten JSON using Apache Beam

Tags: google-bigquery, containers, pipeline, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a `table_a` in BigQuery. It has 3 columns:

- id: STRING
- source_data: STRING (can be parsed AS JSON)
- timestamp: TIMESTAMP

I would like to create a view `table_b` based on `table_a` that flattens `source_data` at the first level only.

Here is the main.py file of my data pipeline (GCP Flex Template):

```
import apache_beam as beam from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions, StandardOptions from apache_beam.io.gcp.internal.clients import bigquery

class ParseJsonFn(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, element):
        import json
        source_data = element['source_data']
        parsed_json = json.loads(source_data)
        return [parsed_json]

class FlattenJsonFn(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, element):
        def flatten_dict(data, prefix=""):
            items = []
            for key, value in data.items():
                new_key = f"{prefix}.{key}" if prefix else key
                if isinstance(value, dict):
                    items.extend(flatten_dict(value, new_key).items())
                else:
                    items.append((new_key, value))
            return dict(items)
        return [flatten_dict(element)]

def run():
    # Replace with your project ID and input/output table names
    project_id = "project_id"
    input_table = "table_a"
    output_table = "table_b"
    
    options = PipelineOptions()
    options.view_as(StandardOptions).runner = 'DirectRunner'  # Change to DataflowRunner for production use
    
    with beam.Pipeline(options=options) as p:
        data = (
            p
            | "Read from BigQuery" >> beam.io.Read(beam.io.BigQuerySource(query=f"SELECT source_data FROM {input_table}"))
            | "Parse JSON" >> beam.ParDo(ParseJsonFn())
            | "Flatten JSON" >> beam.ParDo(FlattenJsonFn())
        )
        
        table_schema = bigquery.TableSchema()
        table_schema.fields.append(bigquery.TableFieldSchema(name="field", type="STRING"))
        table_schema.fields.append(bigquery.TableFieldSchema(name="value", type="STRING"))

        data | "Write to BigQuery" >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
            output_table,
            schema=table_schema,
            create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
            write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE
        )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```

However, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Invalid GCS location: None.
Writing to BigQuery with FILE_LOADS method requires a GCS location to be provided to write files to be loaded into BigQuery. Please provide a GCS bucket through custom_gcs_temp_location in the constructor of WriteToBigQuery or the fallback option --temp_location, or pass method="STREAMING_INSERTS" to WriteToBigQuery. [while running 'Write to BigQuery/BigQueryBatchFileLoads/GenerateFilePrefix']
make: *** [test-template] Error 1
```

Can anyone help?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Are you supposed to use `DirectRunner`, which is not designed for the production run? The error is from https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/gcp/bigquery_file_loads.py#L104. When you use DataflowRunner, you have to pass in a temp bucket for Bigquery FileLoads.

Comment: You are using apache beam in batch mode (since you have no streaming input).  This is totally fine, however, in this case `WriteToBigQuery`implicitely uses `FILE_LOADS`mode to write data. In order for this to work, you need to create a GCS bucket and provide its location to the pipeline. See for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68887892/16622985)